# retrieving file content from servers's response stream and write to file

Tags: ios, objective-c

I get data from server using this code:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [self HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){}
         failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){}];

operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:
       [DOCUMENTS_FOLDER stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.m4v"] append:YES];
```

the problem is: server sent 512 KB data  but it writes more then 900 KB. I think reason is: it writes hex representation of each byte into file NOT BINARY.

Please help: how to write BINARY data?

Comment: Is it working fine instead of size??

Comment: What do you send in the `Accept-Encoding` HTTP Request Header?

Comment: I guess it writes each byte as a string into file. That is why the size of the file is bigger than expected.

Comment: @trojanfoe: I don't send Accept-Encoding. Is it the cause of the problem in my case?

Comment: Yeah I think you need to pay more attention to the HTTP protocol and tell the server what you can accept and check the response headers to see what it sent you.

Comment: @trojanfoe: I set Accept-Encoding to 'gzip' but it doesn't help

Comment: And what does the HTTP response look like?  You can get an idea of the data being sent back by using `wget` or `curl` from the command line.

Comment: Also why would you want `append:YES` when writing the output stream?

Comment: @trojanfoe: I got file using curl and it returned correct data.